# why do these inequalities hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, proof-explanation

I don't get it why the parts I circled in red hold

I know that both $A_k$ and $\mathcal{I} - A_k$ are positive but I don't think that information let us conclude directly what's in the red boxes.

can someone please give more details why those inequalities hold ?

by the way a positive operator is an operator whose associated quadratic form is positive definite and in addition to that is self adjoint.

[image]

Comment: The first is $A_k \leqslant \mathcal{I}$, equivalently $\mathcal{I} - A_k \geqslant 0$, applied to $y = A_k x$. The second is $A_k \geqslant 0$ applied to $y = (\mathcal{I} - A_k) x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm relieved now. thanks !